# WSO2 IS using JDBC as the primary datastore

Tags: encryption, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to configure WSO2 IS to use a SQL Server database as the default primary datasource.

We have reviewed the following guides from the documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+MySQL https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+JDBC+User+Store

we run the command wso2server.bat -Dsetup and everything run without problem, also the user admin exist in table dbo.UM_USER with password "admin"

But when we trying to login to admin console we received the following error :

> Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2015-01-08 22:31:03,647-0500],

We also noticed that the tenant id is -1234. Is that an expected default or indicate a potential multi-tenant error?

In the log file, I found :

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,171] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor} -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container 
>   TID: [-1] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,172] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext} -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,172] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,173] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,173] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,174] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,175] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,175] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,176] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,177] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,177] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,179] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO} -  Cache entry found for Identity Provider LOCAL 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,179] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor} -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container 
>   TID: [-1] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,179] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext} -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,180] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Authentication failure. Wrong username or password is provided. 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,180]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2018-02-27 01:20:37,180+0300] 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,198] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantAddressingBasedDispatcher} -  [MessageContext: logID=f450ee3284096b972cdbd2e258325b986853f2e7012145d8] The system is checking the following  RelatesTo: urn:uuid:d4d7fb9f-b19b-4feb-b88b-3378362a6e22 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 01:20:37,211] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil} -  Authentication failure ... 
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Exception occurred while accessing user authorization info
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.handleSecurity(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:255)

you can see the config files and log with the following links :

link of config file wso2carbon.log

[master-datasources link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JmB4cCzFmHwwKU5EFRwtJCHw6rgQ6EHM)

link of config file user-mgt.xml

[user-mgt Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U_pOjDSvEKAozj4E_gEB5MZhSeF-1yNk)

link of log file wso2carbon.log

[wso2carbon log Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bsyBf9F9rcvvH0dmPVlCF-OxMP49b8ZM)

Comment: Did you disable default ldap as explained in the link https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/60494059?

Comment: yes i did you can see the user-mgt.xml in this link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U_pOjDSvEKAozj4E_gEB5MZhSeF-1yNk/view)  I only have one
UserStoreManager  it's JDBCUserStoreManager

Comment: just a partial info: tenant -1234 is the default tenant so that's ok

Comment: And imho the logs are OK too, all what is important inside is that authentication failed with wrong username or password.

Comment: but i checked the table SELECT * FROM dbo.UM_USER and I found the following column with data :

UM_ID : 1,

UM_USER_NAME : admin,

UM_USER_PASSWORD : admin,

UM_TENANT_ID : -1234

Comment: Can you verify the usr-mgt.xml configurations for jdbc user store

Comment: What do you mean, i think usr-mgt is correct and you can see it from link